# Separate axis of coordinate inside list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, coordinates

Let's say I have a list with its elements containing coordinates of a point like such `[(4,4), (3,4), (2,4), (1,4)]`, and I want to check if a certain point is below or above a certain line or column

So for example the function

```
get_list_below_line([(4,4), (3,4), (2,4), (1,4)], 3, ResultList).
```

Will output:

```
ResultList = [(2,4), (1,4)]
```

My issue here is how do I isolate for example the `X/Y` axis on a given coordinate so I can arithmetically compare with the Line value? Being that each list element is in the format `(Line,Column)`, how can I obtain only the `Line` value from inside that point?
Wouldn't for example using `Head|Tails` obtain a given full coordinate `(2,4)`, how can I get `2` alone?

Comment: With pattern matching e.g instead of  `Head|Tails` write `(Headx, Heady) |Tails` and you get x coordinate at `Headx`.

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog (and others) you can use 'higher order' predicates with library([yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)):

```
get_list_below_line(List, XMax, Below) :-
  include({XMax}/[(X, _)] >> (X < XMax), List, Below).
```

or, something 'good old style'

```
get_list_below_line(List, XMax, Below) :-
  findall((X, Y), (member((X, Y), List), X < XMax), Below).
```

Both approaches apply pattern matching to get the X element out of the pair of coords. BTW note that tuples (i.e. the pair) are just compound having comma (i.e. `(,)/2`) as functor. There is little to gain using them to structure large pieces of SW.

Comment: When did you guys add this? This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive predicate, with one case for `X < XMax`, where the `(X,Y)` point is part of the `Result`, and another case for `X >= XMax`, where it is not:

```
get_list_below_line([], _, []).
get_list_below_line([(X,Y)|Points], XMax, [(X,Y)|Result]) :-
    X < XMax,
    get_list_below_line(Points, XMax, Result).
get_list_below_line([(X,Y)|Points], XMax, Result) :-
    X >= XMax,
    get_list_below_line(Points, XMax, Result).
```

Test:

```
?- get_list_below_line([(4,4), (3,4), (2,4), (1,4)], 3, ResultList).
ResultList = [(2, 4),  (1, 4)] ;
false.
```